# How to remove tensor after sess.run

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow to analyse images coming from external application in following way.

1) Tensorflow and session is initiated when application starts
2) in cycle (everytime when image will arrive following code is executed

```
crops = []
crops.append(_image_data)
image_batch = tf.stack(crops)

_batch_results = sess.run(softmax_output, feed_dict={images: image_batch.eval(session=sess)})
```

It is working but number of items in tensorflow stack is increasing and overal performance for each image over time is descreasing.

How to remove _image_data from tf.stack after sess.run is executed?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Any suggestion from anybody?